# MessageBoxIcon.Questionn to play sound?

Tags: c#, messagebox, audio

I'd like to play a sound when displaying a messagebox Question type.

here's my code:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this item?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

When  the messagebox pops up, there's no sound..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

That's a system setting based on the user in the Control Panel.  If the user has no sound associated with the Question event, nothing will play.

Comment: I'm glad you pointed that, I just verified and my development PC has no sound assigned for Question. I just added it and works just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Hand)
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this item?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: @bjb568 My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Hand) is for playing sound